# new Thread call function, will be executed on main Thread or not?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread and Runnable. Inside the run I call a function.
Will that function be executed in the new thread? or will it be executed on the main Thread?
and the otherFunction(), will also be in the same thread?

Is there any way to debug scenarios like this one?

```
public void startUpload(final Bitmap bitmap){

        Thread t = null;
        t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                reduceImg(bitmap, 100);
            }
        });
        t.start();
}

 private void reduceImg(Bitmap bitmap, int compressLevel){
        ByteArrayOutputStream stream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        String image_str="" ;
        byte [] byte_arr;
        try {
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, compressLevel, stream);
            byte_arr = stream.toByteArray();
            image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT); 
            Log.e("UploadImg", "OK.. immagine compressa e convertita in stringa");
        }catch(Exception e){
   }finally{
     otherFunction()
   }
}
```

Comment: calling `start()` method on Thread object puts `run()` of its Runnable object into a new thread which is going to execute in parallel to `main`. otherFunction will be in the same (new) thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`t.start()` spawns a new Thread. The runnable is executed from the spawned thread. Conversely, if you had called `t.run();` the runnable would have been executed in the context of the main thread.

> Using debugger or simply Log, can I understand which thread execute some part of code?

You can print the name of the current thread with `Thread.currentThread().getName()`, and you can assign a name to the thread calling `t.setName("name");`. This would help you in case you decide to use the Logcat for debugging purpose

Comment: Thank you. Sorry but I have not enough reputation to vote you :)

Comment: there is a reason if during the image_str = Base64.encodeToString(byte_arr, Base64.DEFAULT);  it lock my interface?   if it's a new thread it will be execute on backgrond?!

Comment: it shouldn't. The problem is somewhere else